# Swift can print AnyObject, but can't create String from AnyObject

Tags: string, swift

I have two almost identical sections of code that are puzzling me. Both are functioning in ways that surprise me. The first works, as shown here:

```
let HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &jsonError)
let jsonObj : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(HTTPBody, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &jsonError2)
println(jsonObj)
```

which prints the JSON Object as a string

```
{
button =     {
    name = test;
    "price_currency_iso" = USD;
    "price_string" = "0.20";
};
```

}

The other section of code, which doesn't work as expected

```
 let HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &jsonError)
let jsonObj : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(HTTPBody, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &jsonError2)
let jsonData = jsonObj as? NSData
jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println(jsonString)
```

which just prints out a blank line, which means "jsonString" is an empty string.

How does Xcode know to and is able to convert the AnyObject! into a string when using println, but it fails to create a NSString object from the AnyObject! at the same time?

Comment: What does `jsonData` contain?

Comment: I updated my question to include the missing declaration. jsonData is now initialized.

Comment: jsonObj is a NSDictionary and not NSData, therefore jsonData is nil.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your second section of code, you're trying to create `jsonString` from an `NSData` object which doesn't exist.  `NSData` basically represents a collection of arbitrary bytes as data.  However, your `jsonObj` object is most likely an `NSDictionary` of your original `jsonDict` object that has been serialised and deserialised.

To answer your underlying question, if you want to get a String representation of an arbitrary `AnyObject` type - as you noted, `println` can deal with most of these.  To create an actual instance of String containing the same representation that you would see from `println` you can use the following syntax:

```
let object : AnyObject = ...
let stringRepresentation = "\(object)"
```

Now you'll see the same output from the following two statements:

```
println(object)
println(stringRepresentation)
```

Comment: That's it! I didn't know string interpolation worked for AnyObject. Thanks.